# Not able to ping device with different subnet on gateway and ip adress

Tags: ip, subnet, ping, gateway

I am trying to ping a device with IP 192.168.0.200, subnet mask 255.255.255.0. It is configured with gateway adress 192.168.1.1.

Is it because the gateway subnet, and ip adress subnet is different i am not able to ping it?

Yes ping is enabled on device.

Comment: The gateway needs to be on the same network as the host because a gateway is a host on the network that knows how to reach other networks. You would need a gateway to reach the gateway, and that is not how it works.

Comment: @RonMaupin Perfectly reasonable to have a gateway on a different subnet, as long as both the host and the gateway have static routes to each other? Admittedly such a setup is somewhat unusual.

Comment: @Charlieface, what the OP means is the _default_ gateway on a device, which is to what a host will build a layer-2 frame for packets destined to a different network. That means the default gateway must be on the same network. A gateway on a different network needs a gateway on the source network to reach it because you cannot build a layer-2 frame for a gateway on a different network. You cannot have a host reach other networks without a gateway on its own network.

Answer (score 4):

The gateway address ***must be*** in the same subnet as the interface address. So your device is misconfigured.

Comment: as I thought. Anoying when I must connect to the device in order to change the network config.

Comment: You could change the IP address on another device on the same network and then be able to connect to it. Say you have device 1 with IP 192.168.0.200 (/24 network) and device 2 with IP address 192.168.1.50 (/24 network). To connect to device 1, simply change the IP address of device 2 (assuming you can easily do so) to 192.168.0.50. Then connect to device 1, change its IP address to the correct configuration and then restore the configuration of device 2 so everything is correct. If that is easier than connecting to device1 directly, due to physical access issues, that should do it.